# Got 503 status code while there is pending edit

Tags: discussion

I was trying to edit a question but I was unable because

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot
>   be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.

So what I took the id of the post "29057527" and enter url https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29057527/edit and got the status code is 503 Service unavailable and response text :

> There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few
>   minutes.

[image]

I was not expecting to get 503 status. Can't status code `409 Conflict` be used for this situation?

Comment: `Conflicts are most likely to occur in response to a PUT request. For example, if versioning were being used and the entity being PUT included changes to a resource which conflict with those made by an earlier (third-party) request, the server might use the 409 response to indicate that it can't complete the request.` I'd be inclined to agree with you, except for this.

Comment: @Qix My concern is only that 503 might not be suitable for this.